# Are all known $k$-multiperfect numbers (for $k > 2$) *not* squarefree?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, divisor-sum, perfect-numbers

A positive integer $N$ is said to be $k$-multiperfect if

$$\sigma(N) = kN$$

where $\sigma(x)$ is the sum of the divisors of $x$ and $k$ is a positive integer.

(The case $k = 2$ reduces to the original notion of *perfect* numbers.)

Now my question is the following:  Are all known $k$-multiperfect numbers (for $k > 2$) *not* squarefree?

For the case $k = 2$, the only known exception is $N = 6 = 2\cdot3$.

Update [October 06 2013 - Manila time] :: This question has been cross-posted to MathOverflow [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/144065).

Comment: Chen and Luo proves in [Odd Multiperfect Numbers](http://journals.cambridge.org/action/displayAbstract?fromPage=online&aid=8965487) (preprint available via [arXiv](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1102.4396v1.pdf)) that odd multiperfect numbers *of a certain shape* have a square part $M^2$ and *are* therefore *not* squarefree.

Comment: From a comment in the [OEIS sequence A005820](http://oeis.org/A005820), per Jon Perry - "The odd part of a *triperfect* number is squarefree."  ($n$ is triperfect if $\sigma(n) = 3n$.)

Comment: Nonetheless, *all* of the six ($6$) known *even* triperfect numbers are *not* squarefree:

$$120 = {2^3}\cdot{3}\cdot{5}$$
$$672 = {2^5}\cdot{3}\cdot{7}$$
$$523776 = {2^9}\cdot{3}\cdot{11}\cdot{31}$$
$$459818240 = {2^8}\cdot{5}\cdot{7}\cdot{19}\cdot{37}\cdot{73}$$
$$1476304896 = {2^{13}}\cdot{3}\cdot{11}\cdot{43}\cdot{127}$$
$$51001180160 = {2^{14}}\cdot{5}\cdot{7}\cdot{19}\cdot{31}\cdot{151}.$$

I used [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com).

Comment: It seems that a *closely related* question is:  Are all known (even) $k$-multiperfect numbers (for $k > 2$) *divisible by* $4$?

Comment: Note that every even perfect number is a practical number. I've confirmed that this is also true of the $6$ known $3$-multiperfect numbers, the first $13$ $4$-multiperfect numbers, and the first $4$ $5$-multiperfect numbers.

Comment: Hi, @JaycobColeman!  This question has already been answered in MathOverflow [here](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/144065).  Further details about $k$-multiperfect numbers (for $k > 2$) are also there (including a website on where to pull / extract data regarding the *known* [even] $k$-multiperfect numbers, and a contact person [i.e., the mathematician maintaining that website]).

Comment: At any rate, are you hereby conjecturing that all (even) $k$-multiperfect numbers are also practical (or *panarithmic*)?  Sounds like a good problem to consider!

Comment: I think it's a distinct possibility. I considered the question recently while trying to determine whether every known _harmonic divisor number_ is a practical number. I've confirmed the latter for the first $700$ harmonic divisor numbers so far, but I'm currently working on extending this to the $937$th, $98079457512960$. I'll see if I can manage to confirm some larger multiperfect numbers as well. The relationship of this observation to your question is loose, so I'm glad it's been resolved by other means. To your observation in comments; this implies $4$ or $6 \mid N$.

Comment: I forgot that I had intended to update you on my results from further testing. Perhaps this isn't an appropriate place, but considering the question was resolved on MathOverflow perhaps it should be deleted anyway? Using the factorizations from Flammenkamp it takes only seconds to confirm that the known multiply perfect numbers are practical. You can find the conjecture at oeis. A generalization, which I've not tested nearly as far, is that if the _odd_ part of $n$ divides $\sigma(n)$, $n$ is practical. Equivalently, if there exist $m,k$ such that $\sigma(n)=\dfrac{nk}{2^m}$, $n$ is practical.

Comment: Hi @JaycobColeman, thank you for this update.  My decision for letting this question remain in MSE, is in anticipation of similar questions from MSE users (who do not have MO accounts).  That is, if a person were to ask the same question here after I delete this post, they would never know that there *is* already an answer to *exactly the same question* in MO.  Again, I am reasoning from the premise that *not all MSE users are also in MO*.  It might also be true that *not all MO users are also in MSE*.  I hope you now get my point of view.

Comment: On a happier note, I look forward to seeing a paper of yours that proves those conjecture(s) of yours, re: practical numbers.  At any rate, would be kind enough as to provide the OEIS sequence where I could find the conjecture "All known multiply perfect numbers are practical"?  Thanks again!  :)

Comment: At any rate, @JaycobColeman - are you familiar with Kurt Ludwick's undergraduate (honors) thesis from Penn State University?  Ludwick completed it in May, 1994 but I could no longer locate a copy online.  The thesis is titled "An Analysis of the Ratio $\sigma(n)/n$".  (The term *abundancy index* was invented much later.)  Indeed, Ludwick was the first to prove that not all rationals are abundancy indices, by giving a condition for a rational to be an *abundancy outlaw*.

Comment: See, for example, this [paper](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/VOL10/Holdener/holdener7.pdf) by Holdener and Stanton, published in JIS in 2007, where the term *abundancy outlaw* is coined.  Now, the reason why I mentioned Ludwick's honors thesis from Penn State is because he gave a *constructive* algorithm there for testing whether a particular rational number is an index.  I think Ludwick's *algorithm* can help you test your conjecture that:

If there exist $m, k$ such that $I(n) = k/{2^m}$ and $I()$ is the abundancy index, then $n$ is practical.

Comment: @JaycobColeman -- Do let me know how you go.  Appreciate your last update!  =)

Comment: Perhaps you could submit as your answer the link to [MO answer](http://mathoverflow.net/a/144071/40984). The conjectures are [A007691](https://oeis.org/A007691) for multiply-perfect, [A001599](https://oeis.org/A001599) for Ore. I was recently introduced to abundancy outlaws actually, but was unaware of the constructive result. I have emailed Kurt Ludwick about obtaining a copy of the paper. Thanks for the information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question has been answered in MathOverflow [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/144071/40984).

In particular, the answer confirms that all known $k$-multiperfect numbers (for $k > 2$) are not squarefree.

Additionally, $1$ and $6$ are the only squarefree $k$-perfect numbers (allowing for $k = 1$, and where $k = 2$ corresponds to the classical notion of *perfect numbers*).

These results were further validated by Flammenkamp (in a response to an e-mail inquiry), who maintains a database of $k$-multiperfect numbers.  Here is a [copy](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/144065/are-all-known-k-multiperfect-numbers-for-k-2-not-squarefree/144071#comment372986_144065) of Flammenkamp's e-mail:

> "Well, from memory I know that the two smallest MPNs, namely $1$ and $6$ are not divisible by $4$. And yes, I think all greater known MPNs have a two-power exponent of at least $2$, i.e. are not squarefree."