# Does "sum of divisors" function attain every value of the form $kn$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisor-sum

By the "sum of divisors" function I mean the function $\sigma (n)= \sum_{d|n} d$.

If we choose $k=1$ then it is not possible that we have $\sigma (n)=n$ because $n$ always has at least two divisors, which are $1$ and $n$, so we must have $\sigma (n) \geq n+1$.

But if we choose $k=2$ then we can have $\sigma (n)=2n$ because perfect numbers satisfy this equality and they exist.

So the natural thing to ask is:

> Is it true that for every $k \in \mathbb N$; $k \geq 2$ there exist at least one $n(k) \in \mathbb N$ such that we have $\sigma (n(k))=k \cdot n(k)$ (I write here $n(k)$ to denote dependence of $n$ on $k$)?

Comment: Based on the fact that nobody knows whether there are infinitely many solutions for $k=2$ I tend to suspect that this may be a hard question. (Unless the answer is no for some simple reason...)

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Hi David, nice to hear your opinion. I know that it is still not known are there infinitely many solutions for $k=2$ but I was hoping that there could be some construction that gives at least one solution for every $k \geq 2$.

Answer (score 3):

An integer $n$ is called (multi)-$k$-perfect if $\sigma(n)=kn$. So the question is, whether or not for every $k\ge 2$ there exists a $k$-perfect number. This is certainly true for small $k$. For references see, for example, [here](http://oeis.org/wiki/Multiply-perfect_numbers), and also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/512573/are-all-known-k-multiperfect-numbers-for-k-2-not-squarefree).

So it seems to be an open problem, but Erdös has conjectured that it is true for every $k\ge 2$.

Comment: So my question is an open problem, is it?

Comment: Yes, I think so. If I am not mistaken, it is only known up to $k=11$, i.e., there is a huge number whose "abundance" $\sigma(n)/n$ is equal to $k=11$.

Comment: Do you feel that it could be that there exist some local obstruction which would forbid solution fore some specific/special value of $k$?

Comment: No, I don't. But of course I don't know.